# Flume interceptor in Python

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have absolutely no experience of working in Java.

Can anybody let me know if there is any way to code the flume interceptor in Python?

Following is its Java implementation:
https://thisdataguy.com/2014/02/07/how-to-build-a-full-flume-interceptor-by-a-non-java-developer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, flume does not have a Python interceptor or concept of streaming data out to a process, similar to MapReduce Streaming or Spark Streaming. One of the reasons is the Flume Event is little more complex it has concept of headers and body. It would be difficult to stream your event to Python